# react & webpack4 background-size not work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-file-loader

I'm new to set up webpack with React environment. The issue I have now is that background-size and background image do not work for the background image I set in react component. It worked when I set background-image and background-size and position in the same file. in other words, when I set the image in component, and define background-size and position in scss, it does not work. I believe my webpack setting cause this issue.

-webpack-

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss/i,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: ['file-loader'],
  },
```

-component-

```
  <div className="image"
    style={{
      background: `url(${imageUrl})`,
    }}/>
```

-scss-

```
.image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 95%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
```

With this source, the result I got is that image was displayed, however the image does not cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image does not cover because you override background properties with inline `background` default styles. Remember that inline style has the biggest priority here.

Instead of:

```
<div className="image"
    style={{
    background: `url(${imageUrl})`,
}}/>
```

define background-image:

```
<div className="image"
    style={{
    background-image: `url(${imageUrl})`,
}}/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I made an easy mistake.